# popen md5sum inconsistent with command line md5sum?

Tags: c, file, popen, md5sum

I've written code to transfer a small text file, "mary_lamb" using C-ZMQ to a new text file on the same machine called "meow."

Once the transfer is complete, I run 'md5sum mary_lamb' and 'md5sum meow' to verify that the contents are the same. The md5sums match perfectly. I also inspect the contents of the files to make sure they're good, which they are. I wrote some code using 'popen' to do md5sum verification of these two files, and what's interesting is that the result for the output file (meow) is not the same as the input file mary_lamb, even though the two files are identical.

I've even added a step to run md5sum using system() in C to see the output, and interestingly enough that's incorrect too. Right after the program exits, I read the md5sum through the linux command line and it's different. I've made sure to do a pclose() right after I get the md5sum, but what's going on here? Is it possible that the fact that I'm reading the file changes its md5sum?

Here's the output of the program:

```
running system command for md5
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  meow

attempting to popen md5sum meow...
rMD5: md5_out result: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  meow

rMD5: md5_clnt value: de76ec3d1470e034b82dcb269b11f054  mary_lamb

md5sum mismatch!
```

Here's a manual check:

```
$ md5sum meow
de76ec3d1470e034b82dcb269b11f054  meow
$ md5sum mary_lamb
de76ec3d1470e034b82dcb269b11f054  mary_lamb
```

I have also confirmed that there is only one copy of 'meow' and 'mary_lamb' on this machine.

Here's the code:

```
 //return 0 if eq, else other number.
 int compMD5( char *md5_clnt, char *md5_out )
 {
     char buf[256];
     int total_str_len = strlen( "md5sum" ) + strlen( md5_out ) + 2;
     char *full_command = (char*)malloc( (total_str_len * sizeof(char*)) + 1 );
     //copy strings into full_command string
     snprintf( full_command, total_str_len, "%s %s", "md5sum", md5_out );

     printf( "running system command for md5\n" );
     system( full_command );

     printf( "attempting to popen %s \n", full_command );
     FILE *md5 = popen( full_command, "r" );

     while( fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), md5 ) != 0 );
     md5_out = buf;
     printf( "rMD5: md5_out result: %s\n", md5_out );
     printf( "rMD5: md5_clnt value: %s\n", md5_clnt );
     pclose( md5 );
     return strcmp( md5_out, md5_clnt );
}
```

Suggestions, ideas, comments, all welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It's likely, without having looked hard at your setup, that you have an issue with whether there's a final newline on the data, or something similar.  At least, different numbers of trailing newline a will cause a checksum difference.

Comment: It should be `malloc((total_str_len * sizeof(char)) + 1 )` (or, equivalently, `malloc(total_str_len + 1 )`), but that's not your problem.

Comment: I think the code you've showed us is responsible for the output lines `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  meow` and `rMD5: md5_out result: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  meow`, which agree, so whatever the problem it is, it's not in the code you've showed us.

Comment: Thanks @jonathan Leffler, I'll check for the newline but after the file is transferred the md5sum goes back to being identical.

Comment: As for the code I've showed being responsible for the output lines agreeing, that's not the case. If you see the output you'll see that the output for 'meow' and md5_out result are identical when I run a system(md5sum) and a popen(md5sum) for meow, but they're both incorrect. They are both supposed to match the value for md5_clnt, which is 'mary_lamb' and completely different. Thoughts, @SteveSummit ?

Comment: Main thought for your last question: you have agreement between the two uses of md5sum and disagreement with some piece of magic that you don't show. Given a choice, we'll assume md5sum is right and the invisible alternative is wrong. You've not shown the contents of the files. You've not shown us how the other value is calculated.  You've not demonstrated that the invisible mechanism is calculating a checksum on the same data as md5sum. Sorry, but the problem is more likely in the code we can't see than in the code shown.

Comment: I'll update the post with the contents of the files. The other value is calculated in an identical manner, and is proven to be correct (since it matches with a simple 'md5sum mary_lamb' on the command line of the very same machine. 

I will isolate the code and write a completely new C program that runs just this function to confirm that it's nothing else messing up the popen or md5sum command. Thanks for the good suggestion.

I'll post again once I've updated.

Comment: I tried your code, and it mostly worked for me.  Here are two issues to be aware of: (1) `md5_out` ends up containing a newline, because `fgets` leaves it in.  This can make the `strcmp` fail.  (2) the `md5sum` command typically includes the filename in the output, and that can mess things up, too (especially if `md5_clnt` does not contain it).  Still can't explain why sums themselves are different, but it's not this code that's causing it.